# Integral of a function changing sign

Tags: integration, integral-transforms, laplace-transform

By some numerical tests, we can see that the following function is negative on $(0,1)$:

$$\small f(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{s^{x-1} e^{-2 s} (\pi \cos(\pi x) (s^{2 x}+(0.1)^2)-\sin(\pi x) \ln(s) (s^{2 x}-(0.1)^2)+2 \pi (0.1) s^x )}{(2 (0.1) s^x \cos(\pi x)+s^{2 x}+(0.1)^2)^2} ds.$$

Note that the integrated function change sign for specific values of $x$.

Is there any technique to show that such an integral is negative?

Comment: I presume the integral is $ds$ and then the natural question is what is the motivation for considering this as it looks kind of complicated...

Comment: Yes ds, thanks. For the motivation, this function appears when studying the laplace transform of some derivative of quotient function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, this conjecture fails to hold for $x$ in a right neighborhood of $0$.

Indeed, let $g(x,s)$ denote the integrand. Note that $g(x,s)$ is continuous in $x\in[0,1)$ for each real $s>0$, and
$$g(0+,s)=g(0,s)=\frac{100 \pi  e^{-2 s}}{121 s}$$
for all real $s>0$. So, by the Fatou lemma,
$$f(0+)\ge\int_0^\infty g(0+,s)\,ds=\infty>0,$$
which contradicts the conjecture that $f<0$ on $(0,1)$.

---

The above reasoning is not quite correct -- because the functions $g(x,\cdot)$ with $x\in(0,1)$ do not seem to be all bounded from below by an integrable function, and therefore the Fatou lemma cannot be applied.

The answer still remains negative, though, but we have to work harder to get it.

In what follows, $x\in(0,1/2)$ and $s\in(0,\infty)$, so that $\cos\pi x>0$ and $\sin\pi x>0$.
Removing manifestly positive terms in the numerator of the ratio expressing $g(x,s)$, we get
\begin{equation}
    \frac{g(x,s)}{\sin\pi x}\ge g_1(x,s):=g_2(x,s)e^{-2s}, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
g_2(x,s)    :=
    \frac{s^{x-1} (s^{2 x}-1/100) \ln s}{(c s^x/5+s^{2 x}+1/100)^2},\quad c:=\cos\pi x>0.  \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}
So,
\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x)}{\sin\pi x}\ge\int_0^\infty g_1(x,s)\,ds \tag{3}\label{3}
\ge f_1(x):=\int_0^1 g_1(x,s)\,ds,
\end{equation}
since $g_1(x,s)\ge0$ if $s\ge1$. In what follows, $x\in(0,1/2)$ and $s\in(0,1)$.

Next,
\begin{equation}
    \int_0^1 g_2(x,s)\,ds=
    10\frac{ \tan ^{-1}\frac{c+10}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}-
    \tan^{-1}\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}}{x^2\sqrt{1-c^2}}
    \sim\frac{100}{11x^2} \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation}
as $x\downarrow0$.

By \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}, $|g_1(x,s)-g_2(x,s)|\le2s|g_2(x,s)|\le2\times10^4|\ln s|$. Since $\int_0^1 |\ln s|\,ds<\infty$, it follows from \eqref{3} and \eqref{4} that
\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x)}{\sin\pi x}\ge\frac{100-o(1)}{11x^2}
\end{equation}
as $x\downarrow0$, which implies that $f>0$ in a right neighborhood of $0$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't notice this because of the graph was very thin. So, can we study monotonicity for this function?

Comment: @Migalobe : That would apparently be much harder to do. Do you want to post this question separately?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yeah, it seems harder (after some attempts). I will post it as a separate question.

Comment: Here is a link to the new question https://mathoverflow.net/q/439204/149793