# Monotonicity of a function defined by an integral

Tags: integration, integral-transforms, laplace-transform

The question below is motivated by the related question [Integral of a function changing sign](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438234/integral-of-a-function-changing-sign) and the associated [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/438245):

Can we study the monotonicity of the following function on $(0,1)$?
$$\small f(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{s^{x-1} e^{-2 s} (\pi \cos(\pi x) (s^{2 x}+(0.1)^2)-\sin(\pi x) \ln(s) (s^{2 x}-(0.1)^2)+2 \pi (0.1) s^x )}{(2 (0.1) s^x \cos(\pi x)+s^{2 x}+(0.1)^2)^2} ds.$$

Of course this will help us to determine the sign change of the function which is within the original question.

After some attempts, it seems to me that the study of monotonicity for such functions is not easy.

Comment: `\small` is not obeyed in math mode: $f(x){\small f(x)}$ `f(x){\small f(x)}`.  Also, I think it is more usual to refer to monotonicity than monotony, and have edited accordingly.

Comment: What is the context behind the value of $0.1$?

Comment: It could be any positive number, i took this one to simplify..

Comment: The bounty expires in 10 hours..